# Questions on Xen HVM guest boot: hvmloader, direct kernel boot and simulated BIOS

Tags: x86, virtualization, xen, hypervisor

I'm trying to understand how xen handles booting HVM guests. Any
answers, insights or links to pertinent documentation would be greatly
appreciated...

IIUC, leaving "kernel" and "ramdisk" options unset in your xl.cfg file
means you do *not* want "direct kernel boot": rather, you want the
guest boot to proceed using "simulated firmware": i.e., firmware code that
xen loads into guest memory as a single, contiguous binary blob. As I
understand it, xen actually loads the selected BIOS binary blob from
disk to a specific memory location in the guest (usually 0xF0000) and
then, after transitioning to real mode, jumps to the reset vector in "guest" mode to initiate the boot process. I haven't been able to find much documentation on this, but I'm assuming that the simulated firmware entry point of 0xFFFF0 ensures that the HVM guest will perform POST and do the other things the BIOS would normally do after reset, and that it will do all this in "guest" (non-root) mode. In addition to POST, I'm assuming this simulated BIOS code will attempt to load an MBR from one of the virtual disks specified with the "disk" option in xl.cfg (unless the BIOS selected is ovmf, in which case, I'm assuming the simulated ovmf firmware will be looking for an EFI System Partition and a suitable .efi file).

One of the things that's confusing me is "hvmloader". I see that this
is built as a standalone executable under "tools" in the xen source.
Looking at the inline assembly at the top of hvmloader.c, I see that
there's a call to hvmloader main, which contains a call to bios_load(), presumably to perform the aforementioned load of a firmware blob to 0xF0000. Following return from hvmloader main, the inline assembly transitions back to 16-bit real mode, and ultimately jumps to the reset vector (0xFFFF0), presumably to execute the BIOS/UEFI firmware blob loaded by hvmloader main. This makes sense, but I'm missing some of the overall context: for instance, on an Intel processor, I'm assuming we'll need to be in non-root (guest) mode when hvmloader runs. How is this accomplished? I.e., who starts hvmloader and how? I've seen code in tools/libxl/libxl_dom.c (specifically, the call to xc_dom_kernel_file in function libxl__domain_firmware), which appears to be loading it into memory, but from there it gets a bit fuzzy... Are hypercalls used to start  up the guest DomU? Is hvmloader's `_start` label the entry-point for each non-direct kernel boot HVM guest?

Also, how does the VMX entry/exit logic in xen/arch/x86/hvm/vmx/entry.S fit into the picture here? I'm assuming that that code is running only on the VMM, and that it includes a scheduling mechanism of some sort for switching between the various guests.

I'd be willing to pay for a non-obsolete book that treats these concepts at the source code level, but the most recent one I've found was published  nearly 10 years ago.

Thanks in advance,
Brett Stahlman